# "Pending" text doesn't appear for pending spam flags

Tags: bug, flag-history

After doing some reviewing in the Late Answers queue, I checked my flag history to make sure I was making good flagging choices. I noticed that a spam flag isn't showing the "pending" text, though it is indeed pending. (A previous spam flag that has been handled did get the "helpful" text next to the word "spam".)

[image: an NAA flag has "pending" but the spam one doesn't]

Note the presence of "pending" on the NAA flag and its absence on the spam flag.

Comment: is this the question in cause? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2443964/how-do-i-add-the-disqus-comment-system-to-a-rails-application-in-a-similar-fashi, if no then it's more likely a dupe

Comment: @Vickel The flag was on an answer to that question, not the question itself. Now that the answer has been removed, "helpful" does indeed appear next to "spam."

Comment: I believe this is "by-design" though I can't think of a reason *why*  -- notice that also you don't get told when you raised the flag (like you do with others) and the "helpful" on spam flags isn't given a timestamp of when it was marked helpful.

Comment: I object! I did not answer that question!

Comment: I would tend to say this is a design decision due to the fact that spam flags  and offensive flag have different behaviour http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58032/what-are-the-spam-and-offensive-flags-and-how-do-they-work